# mysql doesn't rollback when error occur when using transaction

Tags: mysql

This is a pretty simple sql command:

```
start transaction;

insert into new_data(textvalue) values ("data1");

insert into new_data(brak) values ("data2");

commit;
```

so the table new_data only has a field called "textvalue". "brak" doesn't exist. I think because I declare "start transaction" at the real beginning so when error happens due to the second insertion, the first insertion will be rollbacked. However, I checked the database, the first insertion still succeeds and table has a new roll "data1".

Can anyone explain why this happens?

Thanks

Comment: what is your table engine? Please post results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE new_data`

Comment: 'new_data', 'CREATE TABLE `new_data` (\n  `textvalue` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL\n) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysql will not rollback for you, you need to run the rollback if you see the error. If you are running the script in workbranch, it you run you sql one by one, so eventually it is commit

This example show you how a stored procedure rollback for you.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_to_insert`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE `_rollback` BOOL DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET `_rollback` = 1;
    START TRANSACTION;

    INSERT INTO new_data(textvalue) VALUES ("data1");
    INSERT INTO new_data(brak) VALUES ("data2");

    IF `_rollback` THEN
        ROLLBACK;
    ELSE
        COMMIT;
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: thanks! will other databases handle rollback automatically when error occurs? because I saw a lot of posts just have commit when they set an example for rollback: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mysql-in-a/9780596514334/re79.html

Comment: it is client issue instead of server issue. i guess you are using workbranch by default it continue run the script even if there is error, but you enable the option of "Stop Script Excution on Error" in "Query" menu. If you have not commit, you will still see the first record, but it is not visable to others.